# Node.js fs.WriteStream behaving strangely

Tags: node.js

I was expecting the code below to print out

```
Finished writing GB translations
Finished writing DE translations
Finished writing US translations
```

But instead it prints out

```
Finished writing DE translations
Finished writing DE translations
Finished writing DE translations
```

Code:

```
try {
    fs.mkdirSync('./locales');
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Info: Locales directory already exists');
}

jsonDefs = {
             GB: {"Item does not exist": "Item does not exist"},
             DE: {"Item does not exist": "Artikel existiert nicht"}, 
             US: {"Item does not exist": "Item does naaht exist"}
           };

for(language in jsonDefs){
    const fileName = `${language.toLowerCase()}.json`;
    const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(`./locales/${fileName}`);
    writeStream.on('finish', function(){ console.log(`Finished writing ${language} translations`); });
    writeStream.on('error', function(err){
      console.log(`Error writing to ${fileName}: ${err}`);
    });
    writeStream.write(JSON.stringify(jsonDefs[language]), () => writeStream.end());
}
```

Other than that though it seems to work fine, everything is written to gb.json, de.json and us.json as expected. Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`language` is overwritten in the `for` loop each time, but the `.on('finish'` executes asynchronously. So `language = 'DE'` effectively occurs *first*, then all of the `'finish'` events occur so it'll print out whatever `'language'` was set to last.

There are a lot of ways to tackle this, but the easiest / one that requires the least amount of changes is to just use `let`, as in:

```
for (let language in jsonDefs) {
```

This will scope `language` for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: ah of course, the classic ```var``` mistake, thanks for pointing that out